# angular fixing scroll position on repainting with ngrepeat list update?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, scroll, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have list of items and I am trying to update the list dynamically on scroll down similarly like infinite scrolling. Initially I was worried about rerendering the all elements, I found one useful option "track by" to avoid rerendering. Now my problem is when add some items to the list its repainting the whole view, with this user losing the scroll position.

How can I fix the scroll position on repainting with ngrepeat?

Comment: Maybe scope is just doing it's work? Binding everything, when you add items, all list is re-binded again, have you tried to use controller instance instead of scope?

Comment: @medettleukabiluly I logged the creation its not rebuilding the dom

Comment: anyway having demo would be better